# Align height of two p-card from PrimeNG

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am having trouble with making both p-card elements to have same height (smaller align to bigger)

[image]

how can i achieve this with following code:

**parent.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <homepage-card header_name="XX"></homepage-card>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <homepage-card header_name="YY"></homepage-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**homepage-card.component.html**

```
<p-card>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <div class="header_style">
      {{ header_name }}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <div *ngIf="header_name == 'XX'; else yy_template">
    <progress-comp class="prog_bar" *ngFor="let item of import_name_xx" [item]="item"></progress-comp>
  </div>
  <ng-template #yy_template>
      <progress-comp class="prog_bar" *ngFor="let item of import_name_yy" [item]="item"></progress-comp>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
    <p-button icon="pi pi-angle-double-down" label="Do"></p-button>
  </ng-template>
</p-card>
```

Comment: Hello! I'm facing the same problem here. Have you solved it?

Comment: I’m not quite sure because it was long time ago and multiple projects ago but as I recall I didn’t solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Both cards are in your `row` container. Give this div a min-height. Then use around your `p-card` another div and set height on 100%.

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="min-height: 20vh">
        <div class="col-6">
          <homepage-card header_name="XX"></homepage-card>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <homepage-card header_name="YY"></homepage-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 100%">
      <p-card ...
      </p-card>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried here but didn't work :(